# Did any country urge China to send more aid to Palestine?

Tags: china, palestine, humanitarian-aid

> **While the United States has announced over $120 million in
> humanitarian aid to Palestinians in the West Bank and Gaza, China has
> only donated $2.06 million (although, during a recent trip to Egypt,
> China’s foreign minister announced his government would be sending
> more aid soon).** For now, China seems content to let the United States
> weigh itself down with this conflict while China offers rhetorical
> support to Palestinians. ​​If that approach threatens its relationship
> with Israel, China is willing to take that risk.

https://www.cfr.org/blog/fickle-friends-sino-israeli-ties-buckle-amid-war-hamas

Did any country urge China to send more aid to Palestine? Surprisingly, the United States sent far more aid to the Palestinians while China only donated $2.06 million. It seems while China offered rhetorical support to Palestine, it doesn't intend to give much aid to help them. Did any country urge China to give more aid to the Palestinians?

Comment: Russia gives similar amounts as China. And only started in 2013 or so. I think the theory of communist countries was that since USA supports Israel, Palestinian refugees are also a US/Western problem.